# Nodejs: Cannot find module error while trying to require unirest module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a unirest client folder among node modules.

On trying to require unirest:

```
var uniClient = require('unirest');
```

Following error appears:

```
module.js:472
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'unirest'
```

I also tried requiring as follows:

```
var uniClient = require('C:/node_modules/unirest');
```

But I get the following error:

```
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:/workspace/postman/webServices/target/node_modules/unirest'
```

I have checked and the index.js for unirest client is placed in C:/workspace/postman/webServices/target/node_modules/unirest.

I need to know 
- either, what is the standard path to require the unirest client (kindly do not suggest installation of package I have already done that but in this case I want to require sourcing the folder)

- or, which module to look in the unirest directory so that I can find the path to require the same.

Comment: which folder are the file that you trying running? and the unirest?

Comment: C:/node_modules/unirest is the one containing the unirest module and the index.js for the same. The contained folders are
> docs,  index.js,  LICENSE,  Makefile,  node_modules,  package.json,  README.md,  tests

Comment: you can't create your file applications into node_modules, you have to create a folder, example: app and into you create your files and install the modules that you need. Probably will work with require('unirest');

like that: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html

change express to unirest for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to docs, the node is trying to do the following: [require](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together)

Comment: ? - I didn't get that

Answer (score 0):

you should to install this npm module in globally.

```
npm install unirest -g
```

Comment: even if u install it globally, the error still occurs